# is there a simple way (macro?) to tell structure alignment?

Tags: c, alignment

I understand the structure alignment is 'implementation specific', but just wondering if there is any simple way to calculate the structure alignment, for example:

```
typedef struct
{
    char c;
    int  i;
} test;

if sizeof(test) - (sizeof(char) + sizeof(int)) == 0 means alignment is  1 byte;
if sizeof(test) - (sizeof(char) + sizeof(int)) == 1 means alignment is  2 bytes;
// ...etc...
```

Is the above assumption reliably true?

Answer (score 4):

Your method is not reliable in the general case: if you tried it on this struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    int i1;
    int i2;
} test;
```

it would give you zero as the result, which is probably not the alignment.

Here is a method that works, though:

```
#include <stddef.h>

struct dummy
{
    char x;
    test t;
};

size_t test_alignment = offsetof(struct dummy, t);
```

Comment: #include <stddef.h>

struct dummy
{
    char x;
    int  i;
};

size_t test_alignment = offsetof(struct dummy, i);

does above work?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "works". It sets test_alignment to the alignment of `i` inside `struct dummy`. If that's what you want it to do, then it certainly does work.

Comment: That would test the alignment of type `int` (I assumed you wanted to test the alignment of the defined type `test`?)

Answer (score 1):

And here's the macro I have in my toolbox (using [caf's technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355302/is-there-a-simple-way-macro-to-tell-structure-alignment/1355331#1355331)) to get the alignment of a type:

```
#define ALIGNMENT_OF(t) offsetof( struct { char x; t dummy; }, dummy)
```

So now you can use such expressions as:

```
typedef struct
{
    char c;
    int  i;
} test;

size_t x = ALIGNMENT_OF( test);    // will likely set x = 4
```

Note that a particular compiler might support a non-standard intrinsic that you might prefer to use (for example, MSVC at some point started supporting an `__alignof()` intrinsic).  My header defines `ALIGNMENT_OF()` using that intrinsic if it detects a compiler that supports it (though I honestly don't know what advantage the intrinsic provides).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your macro has undefined behavior because `offsetof` is not required to work on anonymous structs passed as an argument like that. You can fix it by writing out the portable definition of `offsetof` yourself in the macro body.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a good first guess, then transitively find the maximum size of the largest non-aggregate member in the structure and any nested structures